# Determine the name of the column with a null value nearest the last column

Tags: mysql

I have five columns in a mysql table

> -id
>
> -field_1
>
> -field_2
>
> -field_3
>
> -field_4
>
> -field_5

`Field_5` is the last column of the table i have named `transactions`. If i have a select statement like

`select * from transactions where id = 4`,how would i know the name of the column nearest the column `field_5` that is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use some dynamic SQL to generate all the columns plus a field called 'Nearest'

## PROPOSED SOLUTION

```
SET @id = 4;
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT B.*,IF(A.pos=0,''No Nulls'',',
'(SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema=DATABASE() ',
'AND table_name=''transactions'' AND ordinal_position=A.pos)) Nearest FROM ',
'(SELECT GREATEST(',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('ISNULL(',column_name,')*',ordinal_position)),',0) pos ',
'FROM transactions WHERE id=',@id,') A,(SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id=',@id,') B') expr
INTO @sql FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE table_schema=DATABASE()
AND table_name='transactions'
AND column_name NOT IN ('id','field_5');
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

Just set @id to whatever `id` you want row you want to examine

## PROPOSED SOLUTION'S OUTPUT

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_4 | field_5 | Nearest |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  4 |      73 |    NULL |      14 |    NULL |      23 | field_4 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

## SAMPLE DATA WITH PROPOSED SOLUTION

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS user3286430;
CREATE DATABASE user3286430;
USE user3286430
CREATE TABLE transactions
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    field_1 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    field_2 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    field_3 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    field_4 INT DEFAULT NULL,
    field_5 INT DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO transactions
(field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4,field_5) VALUES
(11,37,14,10,20),(27,NULL,99,10,21),
(NULL,NULL,14,10,22),(73,NULL,14,NULL,23);
SET @id = 4;
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT B.*,IF(A.pos=0,''No Nulls'',',
'(SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema=DATABASE() ',
'AND table_name=''transactions'' AND ordinal_position=A.pos)) Nearest FROM ',
'(SELECT GREATEST(',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('ISNULL(',column_name,')*',ordinal_position)),',0) pos ',
'FROM transactions WHERE id=',@id,') A,(SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id=',@id,') B') expr
INTO @sql FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE table_schema=DATABASE()
AND table_name='transactions'
AND column_name NOT IN ('id','field_5');
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    case when field_4 is null then 'field_4'
         when field_3 is null then 'field_3'
         when field_2 is null then 'field_2' 
         when field_1 is null then 'field_1' 
                              else null 
    end 
from transactions;
```

Comment: I have a row that is like this  id,field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4,field_5 and its data 1,f1,null,f3,null,null   Your code will show the column field_2 to be null but its not closest to field_5

Comment: No, it will show 4. Not 2. did you try the code suggested?

Comment: Yes,i did.I checked it thoroughly.Thanks for the effort.